# Income to property is not absorbed in the same run

Tags: google-apps-script

This is my code

```
function myFunction() {
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var property = userProperties.getProperty('property');
  if(property === null){
    Logger.log('null')
    userProperties.setProperty('property', '2');
  }
  Logger.log('property: ' + property);
  userProperties.deleteAllProperties()
}
```

I created a log in it twice
First time to identify whether `property` is `null` and if it is `null` insert the number 2 into it
A second time is to see if the number 2 exists in `property`

The problem is that on the first run I get the first log `null` and the second log `property: null` and on the second run I get `property: 2`.
Can't this be updated in the same run?

I apologize for my broken English and thank you for the help

Comment: `Income to property is not absorbed in the same run` is not a scripting question

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no because `setProperty()` returns the Property Service not the `property`.  However simply set the value of `property` before `setProperty()`.

```
function myFunction() {
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var property = userProperties.getProperty('property');
  if(property === null){
    Logger.log('null')
    property = '2';
    userProperties.setProperty('property', property);
  }
  Logger.log('property: ' + property);
  userProperties.deleteAllProperties()
}
```

Reference

- [Properties.setProperties()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties?hl=en#setpropertykey,-value)

Answer (score 1):

Since the variable has already been defined it needs to be redefined to contain a new value
The solution is like this

```
function myFunction() {
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var property = userProperties.getProperty('property');
  if(property === null){
    Logger.log('null')
    userProperties.setProperty('property', '2');
    property = userProperties.getProperty('property');
  }
  Logger.log('property: ' + property);
  userProperties.deleteAllProperties()
}
```